# Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running

Tags: docker, virtualbox, openstack, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have Window Server 2016/2019 Virtual Machine(Openstack). On that Hyper-V install successfully. But not able to start MobyLinuxVM.

ExposeVirtualizationExtensions are already enabled on the Virtual Machine box through PowerShell.

```
Docker.Core.DockerException:
Docker.Core.Backend.BackendDestroyException:
Unable to start Hyper-V VM: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 96BDA1DB-4163-4FA5-BEF2-62F1BEC1697E)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 96BDA1DB-4163-4FA5-BEF2-62F1BEC1697E).
at Start-MobyLinuxVM, <No file>: line 688
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 811
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
   at Docker.Backend.BackendNamedPipeServer.<Run>b__8_2(Object[] args)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters)

  System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException:
  Unable to start Hyper-V VM: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

  'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 96BDA1DB-4163-4FA5-BEF2-62F1BEC1697E)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 96BDA1DB-4163-4FA5-BEF2-62F1BEC1697E).
  at Start-MobyLinuxVM, <No file>: line 688
  at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 811
     at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
     at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)

     Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualizationException:
     'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

     'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 96BDA1DB-4163-4FA5-BEF2-62F1BEC1697E)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 96BDA1DB-4163-4FA5-BEF2-62F1BEC1697E).

         Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.VirtualizationOperationFailedException:
         'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.
            at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.View.EndMethodReturnInternal(IVMTask task, VirtualizationOperation operation, Boolean affectedElementExpected)
            at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.VMComputerSystemBaseView.EndSetState(IVMTask setStateTask)
            at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ExtensionMethods.OperationWatcherExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<ConvertActionToFunction>b__0(T x)
            at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ExtensionMethods.OperationWatcherExtensions.PerformOperationWithReturn[T](IOperationWatcher watcher, Func`1 startTaskMethod, Func`2 endTaskMethod, String taskDescription, VirtualizationObject targetObject)
            at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine.ChangeState(VirtualMachineAction action, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
            at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVM.ProcessOneOperand(VirtualMachine vm, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
            at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.VirtualizationCmdlet`1.ProcessOperands(IList`1 operands, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)

   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.<TrySendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean withNotifications)
   at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<StartAsync>b__0()
   at Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<.ctor>b__1()
```

Comment: how did u solve this issue?

Comment: @Loran if you have actual hardware(Not VM) then you can enable VT-X virtualization in system BIOS. If you have any Cloud VM then that cloud provider allows you this option then good go. As this Hyper-V, we required for Linux related containers, I have used two VM in my pipeline. One windows VM for actual code build and then stash those file and in Linux VM build the docker image. 
If you need only windows container then HyperV would be not required.

Answer (score 14):

Work-around

1. Open Hyper-V Manager under Windows Administrative Tools
2. Note DockerDesktopVM is not running under Virtual Machines
3. Under the Actions pane, click Stop Service, then click Start Service
4. Restart Docker Desktop

Its worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue I resolved this issue following below steps.
If you are able to run Windows container that means issue is with Hyper-V

1. Enable hyper on VM  by -
   [image]
2. We must enable hardware virtulization too this can be done by(IT team can help as this should be done on CPU level)
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the VT-X virtualization is enabled in your BIOS

Comment: It's openstack VM, so don't have option to set BIOS