# How to setup docker desktop on windows server 2019 to run Linux images?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, windows-server-2019

After installation of docker desktop getting the below error.

System.InvalidOperationException: job failed with message: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID )

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (). at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.HandleUpdatedJob(CIMConcreteJob updatedJob) in C:\workspaces\main-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 780 at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.d__40.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\main-merge\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 714 ---

Comment: Are the Hyper-V and containers features active?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61279910/service-failed-to-start-the-virtual-machine-dockerdesktopvm-because-one-of-the)

Comment: Yes I have verified that Hyper-V and containers features are activated..

Comment: @blaz yes I have followed these steps. Still not working.

Comment: Are you running on a cloud provider? Nested virtualization is a pain, especially with Windows. [This thread has a good fix](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4470), but I'm not going to mark [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63240986/unable-to-start-hyper-v-vm-dockerdesktopvm-failed-to-start-in-windows-10-mach) as a duplicate because I haven't used Windows server in a long time, so can't verify it.

Comment: @ZacAnger I have tried the suggested steps. Still not able to start the docker desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't.

- Docker Desktop is for desktop, hence the "desktop" in its name
- if you want to **linux containers** why bother with windows server, spin up a linux machine
- if you want **windows containers** on windows server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce